# How to write a function counting number of letter in list?

Tags: python

How to write a function counting number of letter in list?
for example:

```
    letter_list=['a','b','a','c','b','a']


    letter_index={'a':0,'b':1,'c':2}
```

I want to get a result of:

```
    ([3,2,1])
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the most common items in a list, or just count the number of occurrences, use the [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class.

```
from collections import Counter
letter_list=('a','b','a','c','b','a')
counter = Counter(letter_list)
print counter.most_common(1)
# Prints 'a' because it's the most common element
```

And from this you can also get the number of occurrences of each element:

```
print counter['a'] # Prints 3

print counter.most_common() # Prints [('a', 5), ('r', 2), ('b', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using dict comprehension. Also, `letter_list` in your example is a `tuple`, not a `list`.

```
>>> letter_list = ['a','b','a','c','b','a']    
>>> {x:letter_list.count(x) for x in letter_list}
{'a': 3, 'c': 1, 'b': 2}
```

To get the highest occurring item in the list, you could use the `Counter` module as detailed by **@BoppreH**, or you could do something like this.

```
>>> max(set(letter_list), key=letter_list.count)
'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one small option:

```
letter_list=('a','b','a','c','b','a')
def __get_res(lVals):
    unique = set(lVals)
    res = map(lVals.count, unique)
    return (max(unique, key=lVals.count), map(lVals.count, unique))

print __get_res(letter_list)
```